# Cones and partial ordering

Tags: order-theory, dual-cone

A positive cone always induces a partial ordering on a vector space. I wonder if the converse holds, so is every partial ordering in a vector space induced by a positive cone, or in other words, is there a bijection between positive cones and partial orderings?

Comment: On a finite-dim vector space you can define lexicographic order, which cant be induced by a cone.

Comment: As I know lexicographic order is inducted by a non-Arcimedian cone!

Comment: The first paragraph of this:  http://www.ams.org/bookstore/pspdf/gsm-84-prev.pdf   reference seems to say your conjecture is true!

Comment: but that result seem to depend on their assumption that the ordering is not only a partial order, but what they call a vector ordering.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The ordering needs to be partial order and compatible with the algebraic structure of the space.

Answer (score 1):

For a partial ordering $\succ$ on a set $\mathcal{S}$, its algebraic dual, the set of $\succ$-monotones $\mathcal{F}$ is a conic partial ordering. Since $f_j \in \mathcal{F}$ admits the conic combination $ \sum_j \mu_j f_j \in \mathcal{F}$ with $\sum_j \mu_j = 1, \mu_j \geq 0$ so it is a cone. The conic partial ordering $\geq_c$ is defined by $f_j \geq_c f_k$ if and only if $f_j - f_k \in \mathcal{F}$. For some conic partial ordering $\mathcal{F}$ over $\mathcal{S}$, in turn, induces the partial ordering $\succ$. So it is true.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is probability not true. Since you are asking for partial order, you can easily define one that does not preserve under scalar multiplication.

e.g.

define a ($\mathbb{R}, \geq$) such that

(1). $x\geq y$ if $(x=1,y=0)$ or $(x=y)$

(2). $x=y$ if $(x=y)$.

It should satisfied the three properties of partial order. But clearly it does not preserved under scalar multiplication. It should be easy to proof that no cone can deduct such partial order.

Comment: Not sure why I got an down vote. OK?

Lets say there exist a cone $K\in B$ in Banach space and a partial order defined as $a\geq b$ if $a-b\in K$ for all $a,b\in B$. For any $c_0\in \mathbb{R}$, we have $c_0 a-c_0 b\in K$ by definition of $K$. Thus $c_0a\geq c_0b$.

that means any partial order defined by cone in a Banach space is preserved under scalar multiplication. Thus the conclusion.